# How to show the curly braces values in blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Laravel blade view getting values in curly braces like

> {"id":4,"patient_id":2,"findings":"Thiese are the
>   findings","imp":"These are the
>   impressions","attach":"NA","created_at":"2019-06-14
>   15:49:37","updated_at":"2019-06-14 15:49:37"}

My question is how to show these values in the blade?

I have tried the following code

```
 @foreach($report as $rrp)
        <p>{{ $rrp['cnic'] }}</p>
 @endforeach
```

Above code shows nothing. I tried this too

```
@foreach($report as $rrp)
        <p>{{ $rrp->cnic }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Not working for me.

Comment: @Abar Ahmad try `$rrp['id']`

Comment: I can't see that `cnic` key in the input. Are you sure you're trying to get the right thing? How do you define `$report` array?

Comment: @Haru I tried this too.  <p>{{ $rrp['id'] }}</p> The id key presents in array but still not showing.

Comment: @JigneshJoisar tried but no gain

Comment: How exactly do you define that `$report` array? Is this something you declare in the view or you pass it from the controller?

Comment: I have a suspicion, that you're not really iterating over reports, but single report. What do you get if you print just `{{ $rrp }}` (you're iterating properties of the single report)?

Comment: @Haru You are right. it is a single report. I got to lead from your comment.I'm able to show the data like {{ $report['id']}} thank you.

Comment: I'm happy to hear that. I'll appreciate if you could consider accepting this as an answer. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is what I got from @Haru comment.

Data in {  } is not an array. So, we can show the data like this 
`<p>ID :{{ $report['id'] }}</p>`

Eg: variable is not $reports it is just $report.

Comment: If the `$report` variable is a `Report` Model instance, it should be accessible via **either** `$report->id` or `$report["id"]`; Laravel Models are convenient like that.

Answer (score 1):

You should add more code to your question. What data are you getting, data from database, from request, or something else?

If you data is from database and you saved it to a *$reports* variable, and let's say you have these columns:

```
id | patient_id | findings  |   imp    |    attach    |  created_at | updated_at
1  | 2          | some data |some data |  some data   |  some data  | some data
```

And you want to display your text in blade, you could do it like this:

```
foreach($reports as $report){
    <p> {{ $report->id }} </p>
    <p> {{ $report->patient_id }} </p>
    <p> {{ $report->findings }} </p>
    //and so on for every column that you want to display
@endforeach
```

Comment: Not exactly what I want.

Comment: You don't need an `@foreach()` loop for this case, as there is only 1 report being returned (via `$report`), but otherwise, `$report->{property}` is the correct syntax to access properties on that variable.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're iterating on the single report.

If the `$report` contains `{"id":4,"patient_id":2,"findings":"Thiese are the findings","imp":"These are the impressions","attach":"NA","created_at":"2019-06-14 15:49:37","updated_at":"2019-06-14 15:49:37"}` your loop `@foreach($report as $rrp)` will iterate the properties (`id`, `patient_id`, `findings`, etc.).

In your case, the answer is:

```
@foreach($report as $rrp)
    <p>{{ $rrp }}</p>
@endforeach
```

However, if that was an array containing entries like that one, your loop should reflect the existing key. In this example, there's no key like `cnic`.

Perhaps what you wanted to do was:

```
@foreach($report as $rrp)
    <p>{{ $rrp['id'] }}</p>
    <!-- alternatively, if that was an object {{ $rrp->id }} -->
@endforeach
```

Comment: You are right. It is a single report. But It will not show in the loop. we can show it like <p>In p:{{ $report['id'] }}</p>

Comment: Right, a single report is not an object but an array.